# “Rapid coverage” meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I’m reading [Cornell math syllabi](https://math.cornell.edu/linear-algebra-multivariable-calculus). The beginning of “Engineering Mathematics” is the following sentence:

> The defining characteristic of the engineering mathematics sequence, …, is its **rapid** and utilitarian **coverage** of a wide variety of mathematical topics important in engineering and the physical sciences.

What I am not sure is the meaning of *rapid coverage*. Does it mean that the topics are advanced and new, or that the time is always “short” during which the teacher goes through a topic in classes?

Comment: Rapid doesn't mean short, it means quick, fast, speedy, swift, high speed, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter. It means that within a short time, the student has been exposed to many topics (not in depth, but briefly, rapidly).